# how to send json objetct to servlet?

Tags: json, ajax, servlets

```
jsp code:
<script>
//login
function submitForm(thisObj, thisEvent) {
  var userName = $('#userName').val();
  var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
  var myData = {
    "mydata": {"userName": userName, "pwd" : pwd}
  };
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/login",
    data: {
      jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
  return false;
}
</script>

<tr><td><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" size="30" maxlength="30"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" size="30" maxlength="30"></td></tr>                            
<tr><td><button class="button" type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit" accesskey="s" onClick="return submitForm(this,event)">LOG IN</button></td></tr>
    

servlet:
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException{
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String inLine = null;
        String sUsername = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
            while ((inLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sbuffer.append(inLine);
            if (sbuffer.length() != 0){
                JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(sbuffer.toString());
                sUsername = jsObj.optString("userName");
                sPwd = jsObj.optString("pwd");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println(retResponse("E","error"));
            return;
        }
        sUsername = sUsername.trim();
        sPwd = sPwd.trim();
    }
}

web.xml:
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to pass my login/pwd to server side for validation by using json and servlet.
I'm newbie on json.I reference to online example and develop above code. But it not works. Do anyone know what my coding wrong? my already put by login.class under WEB-INFO folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I'm wrong. Its work after I change the ajax lib. from http://ajax.googl... to https://ajax.googl...